# Preserve appearance of TabControl while modifying its ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, controltemplate

I want to modify the layout of the TabControl, so I copied the whole ControlTemplate from the Microsoft site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

On the other hand, I want to preserve its appearance (colors, borders etc.) Unfortunately the Microsoft code does not preserve the appearance, so for example while the default tabs look like this: (apart from text redacted by me)

[image: default tabs]

if I copy the Microsoft style, the tabs look like this:

[image: modified tabs]

Notice the bottom border which is missing in this second case, and also the active tab's color does not transition seamlessly into the tab content's color.

How to write this ControlTemplate so that the appearance is preserved?

Comment: Have you copied TabItem ControlTemplate also? If Not do so.

Comment: I copied the TabItem template too, but when I activate it, it throws XamlParseException because it doesn't find a color. If I copy the colors, brushes and other resources from the same page, it changes the whole color scheme to a blue gradient.

Comment: try applying data template instead of modifying ControlTemplate. could you share your expected output and the data class if any?

Comment: @pushpraj There is no data yet. Expected output is the first picture, that's how I want it to look like, before I even start modifying the layout.

Comment: +1 for finding an interesting problem. I can confirm that Microsoft have provided the incorrect code in the linked [TabControl Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page... I also tried the .NET 4 page, but it had the same incorrect code example. I left a message on the page to notify them of their error.

Comment: I am still thinking why you would like to modify the control template when you have to keep it same as existing.

Comment: @pushpraj I want to modify the layout, add a new control next to the tabs, while keeping the tabs' design the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually copy the actual template code in use by opening the XAML in the designer, right-clicking the control, and selecting *Edit Template/Edit a Copy*. This way you get the exact same template that WPF uses internally.